# rEFInd breaks standby mode on MacBook Air 5.2

Tags: 13.04, macbook, refit

I am dual-booting MacBook Air 5.2 and Ubuntu 13.04 using `rEFInd`, so far things appears to work except when Macbook Air goes from sleep mode into standby mode (dump system state from RAM to SSD), it will not recover when I open the lid or click on touchpad.

Specifically, I can see keyboard light on but no output on screen at all, so it's impossible for me to tell if it has booted into the login screen or not. The only solution appear to force shutdown MBA at this point by holding power button

some [info on MBA standby mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4392)

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/91529/macbook-air-not-waking-up-from-suspend-sleep-with-refind-boot-manager-installed/91531?noredirect=1#91531

Comment: I have this problem as well, Linux mint 15 instead of Ubuntu, and havent really tinkered with it tho, so doubt that has anything to do with it.

Comment: For me this appears to happen only when on battery power, not AC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried the old rEFIt (instead of the forked project rEFInd), it works beautifully with Macbook Air 5.2 and Ubuntu 13.04, and the wake from sleep problem is gone.

So I highly recommend people having this problem give rEFIt a try.

Comment: I have the same problem on my retina Macbook Pro (10.1), I will try using rEFIt. Just curious, how did you go from refind to refit? Did you have to reinstall Ubuntu afterwards?

Comment: If rEFIt works and rEFInd fails, and if you're willing to help with rEFInd development, then trying various versions of rEFInd to isolate when it stopped working would be immensely helpful. You can download any version [here.](https://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/files/?source=navbar) If you can tell me that the problem began with version X, then I can compare that version to the previous one and maybe identify what causes it. Please report the findings to me directly (rodsmith@rodsbooks.com).

Comment: @RodSmith any update on a fix in reFind? , If not perhaps I can provide some testing ground.

Comment: There's a lengthy discussion of the issue [here.](https://sourceforge.net/p/refind/discussion/general/thread/8bd60a7b/) In brief, several people report that installing rEFInd to a dedicated HFS+ partition using `install.sh --ownhfs {device_file}` fixes the problem. Some people report having to jump through some extra hoops, though, so there may be some model-to-model differences.

Answer (score 3):

I'm rEFInd's developer. I've heard another report similar to this, but I'm unable to replicate it myself, since my one Intel-based Mac is an elderly 32-bit model that doesn't exhibit this behavior. Since the problem doesn't manifest within rEFInd itself, I can't simply create a debugging version to give to somebody like you who does have the problem; it's going to take hands-on fiddling with the hardware to identify the cause of the problem and find a solution. The solution could be something like an alternative installation method for rEFInd or a code change to rEFInd, but whatever it is, I'm afraid that I can't find it unless/until I get a computer that has the problem. I have no plans to buy any new Macs in the near future, so this will have to wait indefinitely or for somebody else to find a solution.

Comment: in that case I think grub2 is probably the next best thing, thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: FYI, I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my Macbook Pro 5,3 (2009), not a dual-boot, just Linux, so GRUB2 is used as the bootloader. I have one big problem with the ACPI management. I'm forced to boot with APCI=off or else the machine freezes after few minutes using it. I found that the parameter ACPI_OSI=Linux (in the GRUB config file) makes it work for 20-30 mn before a general freeze. The parameter MAXCPUS=1 makes it work more or less ok, but the Macbook is less powerfull with only one CPU.

Comment: I tested the 3.9.x kernel and the 3.10.x kernel, same trouble. I tested nVidia drivers 310 (tested, recomanded) and 313-updates, same trouble. I tested the Nouveau driver, terribly sluggish... So I guess the trouble is to be found somewhere between the Macbook "faux BIOS" (?) and the power management of the distro.

Comment: Hi Rod, this happens for me as well. One thing Ive noticed is that it happens only with Battery mode, not AC, not sure if that helps

Comment: Rod,  I can confirm this behaviour as well. If you want to try some "live" debugging contact me.

Comment: Hi Rod, I suppose I can try building and trying debugging, if there is a source version which would do this. I have this kind of issue on an old Macbook Air with Core 2 Duo processor, which runs in 64-bit mode with OSX 10.9.4.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an old article and about rEFInd, I'll keep it short.

I recently took my brother his MacBook Air 5.2 in hands because he near identical problems, he is on Ubuntu 18.04 and does not use rEFInd, his laptop has an OWC SSD inside, a simple firmware update and intel-microcode installation seemed to fix the problems here.

(I will update the post if the problem comes back, so far the symptoms seem to have disappeared)